# Windows: C++ monitor if another application is closed (exits)?

Tags: c++, events, hook, exit

Please point me in correct direction to monitor another application (hook?) for its closing (exit) event, and run some code after that.

I guess I will need to:

- find name of that application window/process
- hook to its process
- monitoring window's exit event

Am I right?

Comment: Are you trying to make a virus?

Comment: This is very platform-specific. On Windows, if you know the process ID (which you can get from an HWND using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`), you can use `OpenProcess()` to get a `HANDLE` to the process (assuming you have sufficient rights to access the process) and then use `WaitForSingleObject()` or related function to monitor the process. The `HANDLE` will be signaled when the process exits, freeing the wait.

Comment: [WMI fires events for process creation and termination](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730927.aspx), also (applicable only to Win32 of course)  [Receiving WMI events from C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Camron_Godbout: No, I am not, I'm writting something that clear temp files after closing. A virus does not need some application to close before it doing its job.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Thank you, I will also give it a try.